# Cardboard SDK Unity - way to go native and share properties?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

We are new to unity, and experimenting with a cardboard component.  This is a separate project for now, but we would like to move this code over to our existing projects and have it called from non unity activities/controllers.  But is there a way for the two technologies to share data?  Based on some choices in the non-unity part of the app, it will change what URL the unity part needs to call.  Can we use NSUserDefaults/SharedPreferences for Unity to get data from the other native side?

Comment: As Jason explains, you have to use an external service. Fortunately that's incredibly easy these days.  Just use Parse, Firebase, Pusher or the like.  (It's basically essentially to be totally familiar with these anyway, these days - and it only takes a day or a day and a half to come up to speed.)

Comment: BTW u should just get an oculus  :)

Comment: I don't understand how an external service helps.  The unity component will need to understand decisions made elsewhere in the app.

Comment: Hi Jason, I don't 100% follow you.  Are you going to be having a unity app "within a normal iOS app".  (Always a tricky thing to do.)  If so, a really simple idea is, **write to text files** and each side can pick up stuff that way.  Sorry I don't totally get what you're up to.

Comment: That is what I am up to... unity app "inside to normal app"

Comment: You do indeed have to use the "plugin system".  it's very ... complicated and messy.  Look to the prime31 plugins for some starting points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity can communicate with native code through the plugin architecture, documented here:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html

This is way too big a subject for me to provide more than this frowned-upon link-only answer.

Comment: Its all the same app; part written with the standard iOS and Android stuff, and the other part written in Unity.

Comment: TBC Jason have you actually tried having a "standard app" which has "part 'written in' Unity".  It's a huge pain.

Comment: Have not tried it yet.  I'm wrapping my head around this so I can go back to the rest of the team and present it app.

Comment: If we kept it as two apps, can I pass an intent parameter in Android and something similar on iOS to get that data over to the second app?

Comment: hi Jason, i would basically forget the whole thing, it's so complicated and annoying.  for iOS the simple answer to your question in that comment is "no of course not"